# Problema con .toLowerCase() en prompt

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código básico y funciona bien cuando escribo el nombre.

```js
 var user = prompt("Cual es tu nombre").toLowerCase();
    
    if (user) {
        console.log("Hola " + user);
    } else if (user === null) {
        console.log("Adios " + user);
    }
```

El problema viene cuando le doy a cancelar. Me salta este error en la consola:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

Hay alguna manera de que printe el contenido en caso de darle cancel?

Comment: Hola Sebastián, el código no funciona aquí, salta error. Ejecuto el código en la consola del chrome. Diría que no tengo que tener el javascript habilitado o no. Otro código funciona perfecto, pero esto no.

Comment: Disculpa no leí lo otro mas abajo , pero te respondieron ya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Así ya no genera error

```js
 var user = prompt("Cual es tu nombre","");
    if(user != null)
user= user.toLowerCase();

    if (user) {
        console.log("Hola " + user);
    } else if (user === null) {
        console.log("Adios " + user);
    }
```

Comment: Perfecto! Entiendo perfectamente! Muchas gracias Japh Sxas!

Comment: @jaumeserr si esta respuesta te ayudó, recuerda marcarla como aceptada (el tick a la izquierda, bajo el número de votos)

Comment: Me ayudo perfectamente! Gracias Alfabravo!

Answer (score 1):

Hola el problema es que cuando le das cancelar el sigue ejecutando el  `.toLowerCase()` una solución que te propongo es validar si la variable name tiene algo definido y solo ejecutar el método si tiene algo asignado.

```js
var name = prompt("Cual es tu nombre")
    var user = name ? name.toLowerCase()  : null ;
        
    if (user) {
        console.log("Hola " + user);
    } else if (user === null) {
        console.log("Adios " + user);
    }
```

Comment: Genial! Muchas gracias mariovzc! Funciona correctamente! Ahora entiendo que estaba pasando!